# Understanding why PHP 5.2.17 to 5.3.8 breaks cron jobs?

Tags: php, cron, pdo

*Note - this problem is resolved, but I'm posting here to find insight into what was happening because I don't understand.*

My shared host's default configuration is PHP 5.2.17. When I asked them if I could upgrade to 5.3.X they said sure, and to quote:

> A handler for PHP 5.3 is added to our shared and reseller servers for
>   those who wish to utilize it. In order to utilize this handler, you
>   will need to add the following code to your .htaccess file:

```
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddType application/x-hg-php53 .php
```

> To elaborate further on why we do not currently have this by default,
>   it is due to compatibility issues of older PHP scripts with the new
>   5.3 version. So, to prevent breaking the older scripts on our client's sites we have left the default PHP version as 5.2.X.

So I did that and quickly discovered that this killed my sites using PDO. Calling `new PDO();` resulted in class not found errors in the log.

The shared host's support response was:

> Our PHP 5.3 installations do have PDO enabled already. The issue here
>   appears to be caused by a custom php.ini based on the php.ini for PHP
>   5.2, so it attempts to load the PHP 5.2 modules instead of the PHP 5.3 modules.

ok seems reasonable, says I, now go ahead and fix that!

They updated the .ini file, and added the handlers to my .htaccess, and...

> Your site appears to load correctly, but let us know if you find any problems.

which was true, now the main site and PDO were working fine and a `phpinfo()` check indeed confirmed I was on 5.3.8, but then several hours later a cron job died a fiery death:

> [16-Dec-2011 03:00:01] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/php53/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so' - /opt/php53/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/pdo.so: undefined symbol: gc_remove_zval_from_buffer in Unknown on line 0

and the error log from the cron job directory:

> [16-Dec-2011 03:00:01] PHP Warning: require_once(../pghqClasses/PDO.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/XXXXXX/pghqIncs/initCron.php on line 19

So once again the PDO calls were failing, but this time ***only for cron jobs***.

The support team's final reply was:

> I've seen this behavior before, where relative paths in PHP scripts don't point to the right place. According to the PHP manual, one if the differences between the CLI php and other interfaces for PHP is that CLI PHP won't change directories to that of the script. http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php
>   To fix this, I've added the line:
>
> chdir( dirname ( **FILE** ) );
>
> to the top of your cron script so that, when executed, it WILL change directories to that of the script, therefore making the relative path work. When run from the website, this line will essentially do nothing, but it should make your cronjob run correctly.

And it does indeed work. My cron jobs are running smoothly, and my main site is good, and everyone is happily on 5.3.8, but that last bit of trouble-shooting totally lost me and I'd like someone to explain to me how the includes can fail for a cron but NOT for a `public_html` script, why we're `chdir()`, and so on?

Thank you, and sorry about the length...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `cron` job, which uses the command-line PHP executable is running with the current directory as the location of the PHP executable, or the home folder of whichever account is running the job.  Therefore, any relative paths in the script are resolved relative to that location, rather than the directory containing the script.

By adding the the `chdir()` call you're setting the current directory to the location expected by the script, and therefore your relative paths resolve correctly.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Could you please explain why the main site worked from `/public_html/` but cron jobs failed from `/pghqCron/` despite both pulling includes from `/pghqIncs/` ? That's the part that really confuses me.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the configuration of PHP, but my guess is there's a config line in php.ini, or somewhere else, that tells the PHP handler running in Apache where to find your includes.